# Quantum non-unitary transformation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

Let us say that I apply a non-unitary transformation $\def\ket#1{| #1\rangle} \def\braket#1#2{\langle #1|#2\rangle} \hat A$ to the ket's:
$$\ket{\psi} \rightarrow \hat A \ket{\psi}$$
$$\ket{\phi}\rightarrow \hat A \ket{\phi}$$
Clearly in this case the probability:
$$P=|\braket{\phi}{\psi}|^2$$
Will change. What **physically** is going on here? i.e. why for unitary operators we can perform such a transformation but for non-unitary operators we can't?

Comment: Anti-unitary operator also preserve the probability.

Comment: I believe you have to look at it from another angle. You don't expect your total probability be any different from 1, so non-unitary transformations cannot be physical.

Comment: If you think about an observable in the Heisenberg picture, applying a non -unitary transformation to it will make it non self-adjoint, therefore it will not be an observable anymore. It should not be hard to show that U(n) is the group of transformations that leave your physical observables physical observables, and therefore, "physically", you are transforming something that is "physical" into something that is "unphysical"...

Comment: Physically, stepping back from the details of the mathematical structure of QM fir a moment, I would argue that time evolution is just an illusion as you are always located at some point in space-time. Everything you know about what happened in the past is encoded in your current state. So, you are not actually "changing" anything at all, you just exist at some time in a state that contains information that you can explain in terms of a slightly different state. It would obviously be  pointless if you were to invoke a different state that contains different information.

Comment: So, the definition of the past state and the unitary time evolution are linked, one thing implies the other.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You don't apply "non-unitary transformations" in any physical setting I can think of, therefore I don't see what you mean by what is "physically" going on here. Could you give an example?

Comment: You can apply non-unitary operations probabilistically.  (In case of failure you then of course apply a different non-unitary operation such that the total probability is preserved.) --- But what precisely is your question?

Comment: Let us say that I apply the squaring operation to your age and my age, so my age $X$ maps to $X^2$ and your age $Y$ maps to $Y^2$.   Then clearly the ratio of our ages, $X/Y$ is not preserved.  What **physically** is going on here?   Why, if I want to preserve the ratio, can I multiply our ages by a constant but not square them?  What would constitute an answer to  this question?

Answer (score 0):

I see two sides to your question, in addition to what was already pointed out in comments:

1. For a transformation to preserve the scalar product for *any* pair of kets $|\psi\rangle$, $|\phi\rangle$ in the Hilbert space, it is sufficient that it be an [*orthogonal transformation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_transformation): Say $U$ is such a transformation. If $\lbrace |\psi_n\rangle \rbrace_n$ is an orthonormal basis set, then $U$ must be such that
   $$
   \langle \psi_m | U^\dagger U | \psi_n \rangle = \langle \psi_m | \psi_n \rangle \equiv \langle \psi_m | I | \psi_n \rangle = \delta_{mn},\;\;\;\forall\;m,n
   $$
   which means
   $$
   U^\dagger U = I
   $$
   and so $U$ is orthogonal. Note that unitary transformations also satisfy $U U^\dagger = I$.
2. When you apply a non-orthogonal or non-unitary transformation $V$, the scalar product of the transformed kets amounts to 
   $$
   \langle \phi | V^\dagger V | \psi \rangle \neq \langle \phi | \psi \rangle
   $$
   But note that this is actually a matrix element for the hermitian operator, and so potentially the *observable*, $V^\dagger V$. One ubiquitous example: the annihilation operator $\hat a$ for a many-particle system. It is not hermitian, does not preserve the scalar product, but the scalar product of the transformed kets gives a matrix element of the occupation number, which is not the corresponding amplitude:
   $$
   \langle \phi | {\hat a}^\dagger {\hat a} | \psi \rangle \neq \langle \phi | \psi \rangle
   $$

Answer (score -1):

A nonunitary operator can be thought of as the sum of unitary and antiunitary operators. So let me let $T = aU + bA$, a, b = normalization constants, and we evaluate 
$$
\langle T\phi|T\psi\rangle = \langle\phi|T^\dagger T|\psi\rangle.
$$ 
The product is $T^\dagger T = U^\dagger U + U^\dagger A + A^\dagger U + A^\dagger A$. The unitary operator is easy $U^\dagger U = 1$. For $A^\dagger A$ we have
$$
\langle\phi|A^\dagger A|\psi\rangle = \langle\psi|\phi\rangle.
$$
For $A^\dagger U$ we have 
$$
\langle\phi|A^\dagger U|\psi\rangle = \overline{\langle\phi|AU|\psi\rangle}
$$
and similarly
$$
\langle\phi|U^\dagger A|\psi\rangle = \overline{\langle\psi |UA^\dagger|\phi\rangle} = \langle\psi |AU|\phi\rangle
$$
The probability will then be a rather long summ
$$
P = \langle T\phi|T\psi\rangle = |a|^2|\langle\psi|\phi\rangle|^2  + b^2|\langle\phi|\psi\rangle|^2 = (|a|^2 + |b|^2)|\langle\psi|\phi\rangle|^2
$$
where $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1$.

Comment: If $T$ is linear, and nothing in the OP suggests otherwise, your statement that $T = aU + bA$ also means $T-aU = bA$, or that a _linear_ transformation is identical to an _antilinear_ one. How come?

Comment: $T - aU$ is antiunitary. Both $U$ and $A$ are linear are linear.

Comment: Not according to the standard definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiunitary_operator, which you invoke yourself in your 2nd eq.: If $\psi = \lambda_1\psi_1 + \lambda_2\psi_2$, then $\langle \phi| A^\dagger A| \lambda_1\psi_1 + \lambda_2\psi_2\rangle = \lambda_1^* \langle \phi| A^\dagger A| \psi_1\rangle + \lambda_2^* \langle \phi| A^\dagger A| \psi_1\rangle$. Compare this with $\langle \phi| U^\dagger U| \lambda_1\psi_1 + \lambda_2\psi_2\rangle = \lambda_1 \langle \phi| U^\dagger U| \psi_1\rangle + \lambda_2 \langle \phi| U^\dagger U| \psi_1\rangle$ for $U$ unitary.